# ARKit and File Handling

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, augmented-reality, 3d-modelling

I am trying to figure out how to create a UX/UI design in my iOS augmented reality app where the user can access iCloud files through a file handler, pick an object file(DAE) and its corresponding material file, or pick a SceneKit file, and then once selected, render the 3D model in AR.

Normally with ARKit we have to specify the file path in Xcode of the 3D model we want to use... Is there a way to essentially "plug in" the file path information of the object once it's been selected by the user from a File Handling component in the app?

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/user-interaction/file-handling/) is the link to Apple, so you know what I mean by file handling.

So again, I want to be able to use file handling in my app and select the 3D model file(s), and then after they have been selected, I would like the object to be rendered in AR once I register a tap gesture or something...

The tap gesture, I already know how to do ;)